# How to use _.union from lodash to de-duplicate multiple array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have tried `import _ from 'lodash-es'` and `_.union(user.users.map(user => user.city))`. But it did not get what I expected like: `["city_id1", "city_id2", "city_id3", "city_id4"]`

What is the right way to use `_.union`, or other better way to flatten all arrays and make an unique array?

```
### data
const user =
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "user_id1",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id2"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id2",
      "city": ["city_id3", "city_id4"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id3",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id3"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id4",
      "city": ["city_id2", "city_id4"]
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You can simply do with `Set` and `flatMap` then why use `lodash` here?

Comment: oh, I am learning angular/typescript and not familiar with all the tricks. I would love to have your answer if that works. Would you mind providing your example code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#:%7E:text=The%20flatMap()%20method%20returns,calling%20those%20two%20methods%20separately.) to get the desired result.

This is one-liner solution

```
const result = [...new Set(user.users.flatMap((o) => o.city))];
console.log(result);
```

```js
const user = {
  users: [{
      id: "user_id1",
      city: ["city_id1", "city_id2"],
    },
    {
      id: "user_id2",
      city: ["city_id3", "city_id4"],
    },
    {
      id: "user_id3",
      city: ["city_id1", "city_id3"],
    },
    {
      id: "user_id4",
      city: ["city_id2", "city_id4"],
    },
  ],
};

const set = new Set(user.users.flatMap((o) => o.city));
const arr = [...set];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you still want use lodash

here is the answer

```
const user =
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "user_id1",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id2"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id2",
      "city": ["city_id3", "city_id4"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id3",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id3"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id4",
      "city": ["city_id2", "city_id4"]
    }
   ]
}

let a = user.users.map(item=>item.city)
_.union(...a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `users` array and fill another array `unique_cities` with the result of [`_.union`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#union)

```js
var user_data =
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "user_id1",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id2"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id2",
      "city": ["city_id3", "city_id4"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id3",
      "city": ["city_id1", "city_id3"]
    },
    {
      "id": "user_id4",
      "city": ["city_id2", "city_id4"]
    }
   ]
};

var unique_cities = [];
user_data.users.forEach(user => {
  unique_cities = _.union(user.city, unique_cities);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(unique_cities.sort()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```